# es6 deconstructing an object using a constant

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was playing with es6 deconstruct feature and I did the following

```
const state = { a: 1 };
const ID = 'b';
const newState = { ...state, [ID]: 2 }
```

As you can see I use the value of the constant as the identifier, generating this new object.

```
//newStateValue ==> { a:1, b:2 }
```

I was wondering how the [ID] works?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how it works"? The answer here seems to be "because the language says it does".

Comment: Yes, perhap me question should be where I can find the documentation of the language that said you can do that

Comment: [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: It equals `newState[ID] = 2`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: The `[ID]` part of that code has nothing to do with destructuring.

Comment: That is great Jonas, can you answer the question so I can put it as the correct answer?

Comment: Downvoting as the question shows lack of research.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? (The title and the snippet contains many unneccessary parts) Its actually not related to object destructuring

Comment: @destroyer upvoted cause its hard to find a feature as many documentations lack the searching part

Comment: Why of course, if you're searching for the wrong terminology. The op clearly doesn't differentiate destructuring from object creation (to me implying he hasn't read enough on the subject). A simple google search for "brackets in object literal" would surely eliminate the need for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and its not related to [deconstructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

> property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets [],
>   that will be computed and used as the property name. This is
>   reminiscent of the bracket notation of the property accessor syntax,
>   which you might have used to read and set properties already. Now you
>   can use a similar syntax in object literals too

Answer (score 0):

You can using strings in javascript objects as a key like this

```
   let obj = {
     ['name']: 'Your Name',
  };
```

now the key here s **name** to access its value we use **obj.name** and the same way if you use a variable that represent a string as a key it will be replaced by its value , and that's it look at this example below

```js
let obj = {
    ['name']: 'Your Name',
};
let myName = 'name';
let anotherObj = {
    [myName]: 'Your Name ',
};
console.log(obj.name); // Your Name
console.log(anotherObj.name); // Your Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const id = "b":
 const obj = { [id]: 1};
```

equals:

```
 const id = "b";
 const obj = {};
 obj[id] = 1;
```

As always, the syntax can be found In the Ecma Spec, inside of the [Expressions > Primary Expressions > Object Initializer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) part:

Objects are written like this:

```
 {[id]:2}
```

> ObjectLiteral:
>       {}
>       {PropertyDefinitionList}

The property definition list is just some comma seperated Property Definitions:

```
 [id]:2
```

> PropertyDefinitionList:
>       PropertyDefinition
>       PropertyDefinitionList,PropertyDefinition

A propertyDefinition might be one of the following:

> PropertyDefinition:
>       IdentifierReference
>       CoverInitializedName
>       PropertyName:AssignmentExpression
>       MethodDefinition

And ours is a `PropertyName:AssignmentExpression` , so

```
 [id]
```

is a `PropertyName`, which is a `ComputedPropertyName`.
So the next time, justlook it ip in the docs ;)